# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I keep getting the same 3 errors every time I run this php. I have no clue what I am doing wrong, can anyone help?

Here are the errors:

> [05-May-2014 19:20:50 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query()
>   expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   /home/sagginev/public_html/Nutrifitness/search.php on line 10
>
> [05-May-2014 19:20:50 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows()
>   expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
>   /home/sagginev/public_html/Nutrifitness/search.php on line 11
>
> [05-May-2014 19:20:50 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows()
>   expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
>   /home/sagginev/public_html/Nutrifitness/search.php on line 16

here is my code

`enter code here`

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','sagginev_rob','122989','sagginev_Nutrifitness');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) // Check connection
      {   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  }

        if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:home.php");
    }
    $search_sql="Select * FROM Questions WHERE username LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' OR feedback LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
    $search_query=mysqli_query($search_sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
    $search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
    }
    ?>
    <H2> Search Results</H2>
    <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
     do { ?>
     <p><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?> </p>
    <?php } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
    } else {
       echo "No results found";
    } ?>
    <form>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Go Back Home" onClick="parent.location='http://sagginevo.com/Nutrifitness/home.php'">
    </form>
```

Comment: You should check the manual first.

Comment: ...seems like it's a trend tonight.

Comment: Without any connection to your question - after redirecting using `header("location...");` you should add `exit` or `die` calls to prevent the rest of the code from being executed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. `mysqli_query()` requires **two** parameters. You only provide one. When you see an error message like this the **first thing** you need to do is **[go to the manual](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)**. If you did you would see you must provide your MySQLi link as the first parameter:

```
$search_query=mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the connection variable as the first argument which in this case is `$con`:

```
$search_query=mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
```

Comment: I added the connection variable as the first argument which in this case was $con.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
 $search_query=mysqli_query($search_sql);
```

to:

```
 $search_query=mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
```

You need the connection string in the first parameter and the second is your query. Manual says:

```
mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);
```

Read [more.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)