# NEW to mysqli_* and I need some fundamental help because this is just the first time i am migrating to mysqli_* Functions

Tags: mysqli

I have this code below. And I have this error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

=========================================================================

```
$qry = mysqli_query("select * from tbl_users where usr='$unm' and pwd='$pwd'");
$rec_count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);

if($rec_count == 1){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
        echo "Welcome " . ucfirst($row['fname']) .  "!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484158/mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters-1-given-in)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). When you create the connection to your database server, that is create a `link resource`.

For example:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

when you want to use the `mysqli_query`, you need to provide this `$link` to it.

```
$result = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry);
```